# How do I make async http get requests in Java?

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, get

I wrote a program where I call many http get request. It takes like half a minute till all the get requests are done but it needs to be done within a second, this can be achieved with calling this method asynchronously, right? But how?

This is what my get request looks like:

```
public static String dataRequest(String link) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(link);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
    }
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
    String output;
    String result = "";
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result += output;
    }
    conn.disconnect();
    return result;
}
```

I tried using RxJava but I couldn't get it to work at all. I'm in a Maven JavaFx project. This method is in my `getData` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using thread with ForkJoinPool

For example -> https://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join